# Problema en resolucion de reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rewriterule

tengo un problema en la redireccion desde una url publica hacia un pod de kubernetes. Para dar un poco de detalle, tengo un api gateway en aws, y 3 stage (dev, qa y prod). Esto me genera las siguientes urls

```
api.example.com/dev
api.example.com/qa
api.example.com/uat
```

Bajo estas urls, corren las apis, por ejemplo api.metricles.com/dev/cliente/guardar

Y asi cada una de las apis.

EL problema que estoy teniendo, es que desde el api gateway se llama a un NGINX que forwardea hacia los 3 backends (de cada ambiente) que estan dentro de un cluster de kubernetes.

La idea es que si llegas por la url api.metricles.com/dev te mande a los pods de desarrollo, si entras por api.metricles.com/test te mande a los pods de test, y lo mismo con UAT. Dentro de el backend no existe /dev o /qa, sino que es sobre el root.

Para esto configure en el nginx la siguiente configuracion

```
http {
  upstream backend_dev {
    server backend.dev.svc.cluster.local:3000;
  }
  server {
      listen       8080;
      server_name   api.example.com;
      location ~ /dev/(.*)$ {
          proxy_pass http://backend_dev/$1;
      }
  }
```

El problema es que cuando hago un request, no me resuelve la llamada, devolviendome error 404. En cambio si el location es ~ /(.*)$ me funciona todo perfecto. Pero no puedo segmentar lo que necesito.

Probe muchas otras formas, pero no logro poder resolver esto que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

no se si podre ayudar en algo llevo poco tiempo usando reverse proxy.

Por lo que tengo entendido cuando consultas api.example.com/dev te manda el error 404 porque esta intentando buscar en http://backend_dev el directorio /dev/ pero como en el proxy_pass http://backend_dev esta sin /dev/ no te va a mostrar nada.

Creo que estas buscando algo así

```
location /dev/ {
      proxy_pass http://backend_dev/dev/;
```

Espero haber ayudado en algo